# Multithreading error within boost::shared_ptr code

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency

I am using visual studio and I keep getting an exception on the following line of the boost::shared_ptr code:

```
void release() // nothrow
{
    if( BOOST_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT( &use_count_ ) == 0 )
    {
        dispose();
        weak_release();
    }
}
```

I think it is multithreading because it is very random when it occurs.I'm struggling to get more details.

I share an `unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>>` amongst several threads. I think the error is due to different threads accessing the unordered_map at the same time (the threads don't access the same elements of the unordered_map).

MyClass contains an unordered_map and a set. The threads add numbers to these data structures. So if I had:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void addToMap(double a, long b);
    void addToSet(double c);
private:
    unordered_map<double, long> a;
    set<double> b;
}
```

- Thread 1: processes element 1 of `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >`
- Thread 2: processes element 2 of `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >`
- Thread 3: processes element 3 of `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >`
- Thread 4: processes element 4 of `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >`

I do not have any locks in my code. Could someone please advise how I could potentially solve this problem (even if it means making the code slower)? Do I just need to insert mutexes inside each MyClass object? However it seems to be the boost::shared_ptr of the MyClass object which is causing the exception?

I do not pass any `boost::shared_ptr` objects by reference/pointer.

Comment: Explain how given two code snippets are connected?

Comment: You have posted code in which a shared_ptr function throws an exception, and yet the code you posted contains no shared_ptr objects.  This will make it difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @AndyNewman all I can see is Visual Studio breaking on that line in the boost shared_ptr header.

Answer (score 2):

`operator[]` modifies the container, and is therefore not safe to access concurrently. Your program has a data race. Generally, non-`const` member functions of standard library objects are not safe for simultaneous access. C++11 §23.2.2 lists some special exceptions for containers:

> <sup>1</sup> For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be `const`: `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `front`, `back`, `data`, `find`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, `equal_range`, `at` and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, `operator[]`.
>
> <sup>2</sup> Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.

So for `unordered_map`, it's unsafe for multiple threads to simultaneously call `operator[]` - but it is safe for them to access distinct objects in the container simultaneously. Protecting the lookup of elements is sufficient, e.g.:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(some_mutex);
auto& foo = my_map["key"];
lk.unlock();
foo += 42;
```

Alternatively, if you only want to access existing elements in the map - and not add new default constructed elements - you can use `find` without external synchronization per the standard quote above.

Comment: Ohhhhhh!!!! So I should put mutex locks at the beginning and end of member functions which access shared unordered_maps via []. Btw why does the error show up in the shared_ptr code instead of the unordered_map code (or where the unordered_map is accessed)?

Comment: Should I write a wrapper class around unordered_map with mutexes protecting the member functions?

Comment: There's some more explanation now that I'm not on a phone. As for why the error happens in `shared_ptr` code, \*handwaving\* undefined behavior?